# How to get notifications about changes in bound collection?

Tags: c#, wpf

I defined an attached dependency property of collection type:

```
var selSrcPropMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(SelectionSourceChanged);
SelectionSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectionSource",
                                                        typeof(IEnumerable), 
                                                        typeof(SelectionHelper), 
                                                        selSrcPropMetadata);
```

Property change callback works only once when binding is applied.
But *how can I get the notifications about bound collection changes*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SelectionSourceChanged, check if the new source value implements INotifyCollectionChanged. If it does, cast it and subscribe to its CollectionChanged event.

Comment: And it definitely does cause ICollectionView inherits INotifyCollectionChanged. Looked at CollectionViewSource erroneously. thanks.